# list of custom class converted to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have such a class

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

where x,y,z are `float`

and I want to do this:

```
p = Point(0,0,0)
arr_p = np.array(p)
arr_pts = np.array([p])
```

what I expect:

```
>>> arr_p
array([0., 0., 0.])
>>> arr_pts
array([[0., 0., 0.]])
```

and both have `dtype=np.float64`

How can I customize my class to achieve this?

What I've tried:
I saw some comments in numpy.array

```
        object : array_like
            An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
            __array__ method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.
```

so I simply added

```
    def __array__(self):
        return [self.x, self.y, self.z]
```

But it doesn't work....I don't know what does it mean by `array`, is it C level thing that we need to manage the memory layout?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: it is not clear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you give example input/output?

Comment: What's `p`?  A list of `Point` instances?  Be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `__len__` and `__getitem__` method:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __len__(self):
        return 3

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z)[idx]
```